# How Object constructor comes in the prototype object of any function?

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototype-programming

In the code below

```
function Hello(){
      //
 }

console.dir(Hello);
```

[image]

My question is:

From where and how **Object** comes in the prototype object of Hello ?

What is happening behind the scenes to bring Object there ?

Answer (score 3):

Do not confuse `prototype` as property of a function with its actual prototype (accessible through `__proto__`/`getPrototypeOf()`  and used in name resolution mechanism, among other things).

In your example, `Hello.prototype` is used as a shared prototype for all the objects created with Constructor pattern: that is, when this function is invoked with `new` operator. And yes, this prototype is essentially an object:

```js
function Hello() {}
console.log(Hello.prototype); // {}
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Hello)); // function () { [native code] }

const newHello = new Hello();
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(newHello) === Hello.prototype); // true

const anotherHello = new Hello();
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(anotherHello) === Hello.prototype); // true
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(newHello) === Object.getPrototypeOf(anotherHello)); 
// apparently true as well
```

And that's the key idea of prototype-based object model in JS: all the things that are shared between instances are stored just once.

Note that arrow functions do not have `prototype` property on them (as you're not expected to use them as constructors):

```js
const FatArrowHello = () => {};
console.log(FatArrowHello.prototype); // undefined
const newFatArrowHello = new FatArrowHello();
// VM424: 1 Uncaught TypeError: FatArrowHello is not a constructor
// at < anonymous >: 1: 18
```

Answer (score 1):

> From where and how Object comes in the prototype object of Hello ?

It doesn't, but that console display does make it seem like that. The prototype of the object on `Hello.prototype` is actually `Object.prototype`, not `Object`:

```js
function Hello() {
}
console.dir(Hello);
console.log(Hello.prototype.__proto__ === Object); // false
console.log(Hello.prototype.__proto__ === Object.prototype); // true
```

The console is showing `Object` there as the **type** (loosely speaking) of `Hello.prototype.__proto__`, not as its value.

*(Note: I've used `__proto__` above because that's how the console was showing it to you in your example, but I strongly recommend **not** using the `__proto__` accessor in code. Use `Object.getPrototypeOf` instead.)*

---

I think you know this, but for completeness: The reason that `Hello.prototype`'s prototype is `Object.prototype` is that the `prototype` property of a traditional function (and `class` constructors) is created by the JavaScript engine when it creates the function. For traditional functions and base classes, that prototype object is created as though with an object literal: `{}`. So that object has `Object.prototype` as its prototype. (Classes using `extends` work slightly differently.)